# Полурабочая программа: помогите найти ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = input()
n = list(n)
if len(n) < 8:
    print('Короткий!')
else:
    b = input()
    b = list(b)
    i = 1
    if len(n) == len(b):
        while True:
            if b[i] == n[i]:
                if i == len(n):
                    print('OK')
                    break
                else:
                    i += 1
            else:
                print('Различаются.')
                break
```

Не вижу ошибки, помогите исправить.

Comment: break после 'ОК', и len(n)-1

Comment: 1. что этот код _должен_ делать (но не делает) 2. какая выводится ошибка/что выдается в результате и чем оно уличается от того, что ожидалось?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как сказал @vp_arth, надо:

```
if i == len(n):
    print('OK')
```

заменить на:

```
if i == len(n) - 1:
    print('OK')
    break
```

а также `i = 1` надо заменит на `i = 0` потому что индексация начинается с нуля.

И зачем так сложно если можно же просто написать

```
if n == b:
    print('ОK')
else:
    print('Различаются.')
```